# Measure Babel compilation performance (per file or module)

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm trying to figure out how to extract some **information** from **`babel` compilation process**.

More specifically, when I run `babel` (no matter if using Webpack's [`babel-loader`](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader), test frameworks' [transformers](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react#custom-transformers), [Babel's CLI](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli), etc) I'd need to **extract** some **information** for **each compiled file**. Like:

- file path
- time taken to compile
- any other meta data?

### What I've tried so far

#### Speed Measure Plugin for Webpack ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speed-measure-webpack-plugin))

Works fine but it provides only Webpack's loaders running time. No info about single compiled files.

#### Hook into Webpack's compiler/compilation instance

I considered [writing a Webpack plugin](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/How-to-write-a-plugin) to hook into the compilation process as described [here](https://gist.github.com/rowanoulton/c092b27d7c8cf0c225beaabad5fd11d1), but I couldn't find the proper hooks to recognize a file being processed by `babel`.

### Updates

I guess @kidroca pointed out the right direction. More specifically I understand that Babel’s [`wrapPluginVisitorMethod` option](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#wrappluginvisitormethod) is the key for hooking into Babel compilation process.

See `babel-minify`’s [timing plugin](https://github.com/babel/minify/blob/6b8bab6bf5905ebc3a5a9130662a5fef34886de4/scripts/plugin-timing.js).

Related threads:

- https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5340
- https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2206
- https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/3659
- https://github.com/babel/minify/pull/93
- https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/3659

### Updates 28/04/18

I eventually tried to **wrap a solution** into a tool I called [babel-timing](https://github.com/toomuchdesign/babel-timing).

Comment: Just an idea, instead of creating another plugin, just intercept the babel-loader.

Comment: ^ why stop at the loader, intercept `babel.transform`. Squeeze your measure logic right into the source code of babel if possible.

Comment: I'd definitely like to find a solution involving babel only, in order to be able to measure compilation time independently from the surrounding tooling.

Comment: `babel-minify`'s plugin-timing and benchmark seems the way to go for tapping inside babel. I'm not sure whether the `wrapPluginVisitorMethod` can be passed from an external config like .babelrc. If that's possible it will allow you to integrate this benchmark/analysis with no modification to babel code and run it for any project that uses babel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `@babel/core` and `babel.transformSync(code)` which will return 
[Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (AST) information along with some other data. And you can also add some logic to measure the performance of this method

I've setup a minimal repo and played with it myself  a little bit: https://github.com/kidroca/babel-meta

Basically you can run `npm run analyze-file ./es6-src/es6-module.js` or `npm run analyze-dir ./es6-src/es6-module.js` and checkout the results

This will return:

```
{
  "filename": "/full/path/to/src/file.js",
  "cwd": "current/dir",
  "ast": "ast information json - lines, comments, and other info",
  "executionTime": "execution time in ms",
  /* a lot of other info */
}
```

You can modify the `analyze.js` file to filter out the info you need
You can modify the `.babelrc` file to control the transformation and add/remove plugins